Installing jupyterlab through pip install, warnings on path
When I tried launching JupyterLab from Anaconda Navigator, for some reason it opens up VS Code with html:
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>     <meta charset="UTF-8">     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8965/lab?token=0888ebdb28d7552347f31db3bcb70beb8a95777b273869d1" />     <title>Opening Jupyter Application</title> </head> <body>  <p>     This page should redirect you to a Jupyter application. If it doesn't,     <a href="http://localhost:8965/lab?token=0888ebdb28d7552347f31db3bcb70beb8a95777b273869d1">click here to go to Jupyter</a>. </p>  </body> </html>
if I click that URL, it opens a blank screen. So I tried installing it through the terminal with  pip install jupyterlab --user   which seemed to work but I got a lot of warnings:
WARNING: The script send2trash.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script pyjson5.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script normalizer.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script pybabel.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel.exe, jupyter-kernelspec.exe and jupyter-run.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script httpx.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script jsonschema.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The scripts ipython.exe and ipython3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script jupyter-trust.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script jupyter-execute.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script jupyter-events.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The scripts jupyter-dejavu.exe and jupyter-nbconvert.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The script jupyter-server.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.   WARNING: The scripts jlpm.exe, jupyter-lab.exe, jupyter-labextension.exe and jupyter-labhub.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\julia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.  

then, if i try to run jupyterlab by just typing it into the terminal, it doesn't know what jupyter is.
expected to open jupyter lab through pip install.

When VSCode was opening your HTML, you just needed to assign your browser to handling  handling files with .html as the extension again. Here covers how to fix that by setting the default application to your browser for handling .html files. (Now you may have made things worse by installing Jupyter a second way. Hopefully not. It is always best to be cautious when something seems odd.)
